# Using Selection args in Query with Or Operation

Tags: android, sql, arguments, where-clause

i'm actually working with a Database and need another Cursor than i actually use.
But i have a problem with the where and the Selection Args Statements.
My Issue is that i want to check if 1 of my 4 Columns in the Where clause,have one of 4 possible Values. I tried it with:

```
String where = "String1 IN(?,?,?,?) OR String2(?,?,?,?) OR String3(?,?,?,?) OR
String4(?,?,?,?);
Cursor c = myDatabase.query("Table1",new String[]{"String1","String2","String3","String4",where,new String[]{"Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4"},null,null,null);
```

But that doesn't work as i hope and just use the first Value and check it, but not the other 3.

Hope u can help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to mention the parameters once.  This might be better for your purpose:

```
where (? in (string1, string2, string3, string4) or
       ? in (string1, string2, string3, string4) or
       ? in (string1, string2, string3, string4) or
       ? in (string1, string2, string3, string4)
      )
```

Comment: Not sure if u meant it like that, but i changed it now to:                   
    Where = "Value1 in (string1, string2, string3, string4) or
       Value2 in (string1, string2, string3, string4) or
       Value3 in (string1, string2, string3, string4) or
       Value4 in (string1, string2, string3, string4)";
But i get the Error, that a Column ist missing, which is not really missing :(